# Sending Pdf file to Printer in a sequnece

Tags: excel, vba

Im quite new in excelvba. Im trying to generate a code that allows to sending pdfs to printer in a sequence.
I developed a code but code doesnt understand the sequence(sort by name). How can I correct my code?

Code is here

```
Sub Send_to_Printer_by_in_a_sequence()
    Dim way As String, Pdfs As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    way = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    Pdfs = Dir(way & "*.pdf")
    
    While Pdfs <> ""
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(way & Pdfs).InvokeVerb ("Print")
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4)
        Pdfs = Dir
    Wend
    
    On Error GoTo 10
    AppActivate "Acrobat Reader", True
    SendKeys "%{F4}", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
    
10  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "All pdfs has been sent to printer."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the names of your pdf files, sort the array as you like and send to printer in any sequence picking names from the array

```
Sub collectnames()
Dim way As Object, wFolder as object, Pdfs() As String
count = 0
Set way = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wFolder = way.GetFolder(Path)
For Each x In wFolder.Files
If InStr(1, x.Name, ".pdf") > 0 Then
count = count + 1
Pdfs(count) = x.Name
End If
 Next x
 End sub
```